# $(x, y) \in$ $\mathbb{R} $, $x^2 +y^2 +xy=4$ and $x^4 +y^4 +(xy) ^2 =8$ calculate : $ x^6+(xy)^3+y^6$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, polynomials, factoring, alternative-proof

I did the answer, but I want new ideas for answer

My answer :

$x^2 +y^2 =4-xy  $ $\Rightarrow $ $(*)$ $( x^2 +y^2) ^2 =(4-xy) ^2$

$ x^4 +y^4+2 (xy) ^2 = 8+(xy)^2$ $ \Rightarrow$ $(**)$ $(x^2 +y^2) ^2 =8+(xy) ^2$

$(*, **) $ $\Rightarrow$ $8+(xy) ^2 =(4-xy)^2$
$\Rightarrow$ $ 8+(xy) ^2= 16-8xy+(xy)^2$
$\Rightarrow$  (***) $xy=1$

$(***)$ $\Rightarrow$ $ x^2 +y^2 =3$
$\Rightarrow$ $ x^2 =3-y^2$  and $ y^2 = 3-x^2 $
$\Rightarrow$ $ x^6 =(3-y^2) ^3 and  y^6 =(3-x^2) ^3 $
$\Rightarrow$ $ x^6 +y^6 =(3-y^2)^3 +(3-x^2) ^3$
$\Rightarrow$ $ x^6 +y^6 = - x^6 + 9 x^4 - 27 x^2 - y^6 + 9 y^4 - 27 y^2 + 54 $
$\Rightarrow $ $2(x^6 +y^6) = 9(x^4 +y^4) - 27(x^2 +y^2) +54 $
$\Rightarrow$ $ x^6 +y^6 = \frac{9(7)-27(3)+54}{2}= 18 $

Finally :

$x^6 +y^6 +(xy) ^3 =19 $

Because
$xy =1$ and$  x^6+y^6 =18$

Comment: `$\mathbb{R}$` produces $\mathbb{R}$.  `$\implies$` produces $\implies$.

Answer (score 2):

$$8=x^4+x^2y^2+y^4=(x^2+y^2)^2-x^2y^2=$$
$$=(x^2-xy+y^2)(x^2+xy+y^2)=4(x^2+y^2-xy),$$ which gives $$x^2+y^2-xy=2,$$ $$x^2+y^2=3,$$$$xy=1$$ and
$$x^6+y^6+x^3y^3=(x^2+y^2)(x^4-x^2y^2+y^4)+x^3y^3=3(8-2)+1=19.$$

Comment: how did you get the value of $(xy) $

Comment: @Anas chaabi  $xy=x^2+y^2-(x^2+y^2-xy)=3-2=1$.

Comment: @Micheal Rozenberg Other methods for find value of xy, we can$ x^2 +y^2 - xy=2$,and$ x^2 +y^2 +xy=4$,so $x^2 +y^2 +xy= 2x^2 +2y^2 - 2xy,$ $\Rightarrow$ $ x^2 +y^2 - 3xy=0$, $\Rightarrow$ $4-xy-3xy=0$ $ \Rightarrow$ $xy=1$, also exist other methods for find value of $xy$ look at my answer

Comment: @Anas chaabi  I agree. But for solving of your problem by my way we need also $x^2+y^2$. Just you looked for another ideas.

Comment: Yes I agree with you

Comment: yes I was looking for others ideas

Answer (score 0):

Hint

$$x^4+y^4+x^2y^2=(x^2+y^2)^2-(xy)^2=?$$

So, we have $x^2+y^2=?$ and $xy=?$

We don't need to find $x,y$

Now $$x^6+y^6+x^3y^3=(x^2+y^2)^3-3x^2y^2(x^2+y^2)+(xy)^3=?$$